# Export multiple interfaces from a Typescript file

Tags: typescript

There are multiple interfaces in my typescript file which I need to export. Something like:

```
interface A {
 ...
}

interface B {
 ...
}
```

Then in another file I need to use

```
const var : A
```

I have searched and tried multiple things, but till not only export default works for me. But export default only works for one interface. I can't export multiple. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: What's wrong with qualified export?

Comment: @majkrzak I have tried export, export type, export instance and a bunch of others, none of them compiles

Comment: what exactly is not working, the export or the import?

Answer (score 4):

Should work:

```
export interface A {
 ...
}

export interface B {
 ...
}
```

```
import type { A, B } from '...';

const var1: A = ...
```

Comment: According to OP it does not ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem :D... In one (generated) ts file i had multiple exported interfaces, and including multiple interfaces worked. In another file it didn't. I am having a vue3 project. Recompiling the project / restarting the development server resolved the issue in the end. (i swear i tried that multiple times and it did not work at first ;)